# Call a function with some parameters in a vector variable

Tags: r

I have a dataframe, and a function I use to mark specific cases in it (The following is an example to make things more concrete. The actual dataframe and function are much more complicated).

```
df = data.frame(number = c(1,2,3,4),
                type1   = c("A","A","B","B"),
                type2   = c("A","B","A","B"),
                var1   = c(1,2,3,4),
                var2   = c(1,2,3,4) )

FilterMark <- function (fun_data, cond_type1, cond_type2) {
  fun_data$filter <- FALSE
  fun_data$filter [which(fun_data$type1 == cond_type1 & 
                           fun_data$type2 == cond_type2 )]  <- TRUE
  return(fun_data$filter)
}
```

I need to call this function multiple times, with various conditions. I want use a vector to define the conditions for each such call. for example:

```
conds = c("A","A")

df$case1[FilterMark(df, conds)] <- TRUE
```

But this doesn't work. The function interprets `conds` as a one parameter, instead of breaking the vector into two parameters.

Is there a way to call the function in such a way?
(I already tried `do.call`, but couldn't get it to work...)

Comment: With `do.call` it would be `do.call("FilterMark", c(list(df), conds))`

Comment: This works, thanks! When I tried `do.call`, I missed putting the `df` inside a `list()`. If you provide that as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score -1):

Do you really need an specific function for that?

```r
library(tidyverse)

df = data.frame(
  number = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  type1   = c("A", "A", "B", "B"),
  type2   = c("A", "B", "A", "B"),
  var1   = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  var2   = c(1, 2, 3, 4)
)

df |>
  mutate(case1 = type1 == "A" & type2 == "A")
#>   number type1 type2 var1 var2 case1
#> 1      1     A     A    1    1  TRUE
#> 2      2     A     B    2    2 FALSE
#> 3      3     B     A    3    3 FALSE
#> 4      4     B     B    4    4 FALSE
```

Comment: I do, as i wrote in the original post, the actual usage would be with multiple conditions and multiple calls of the function. If I only wanted to subset the data by two variables I wouldn't be asking the question...

Comment: The call to `mutate` doesn't filter: it creates a new column *case1*. Your function FilterMark is so simple that the source code would be more legible if you inline it (if you don't use a function and just write the conditions).